# How can I ensure browser compatibility for the webcrypto API in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, browser, webcrypto-api

So, what I'm trying to achieve is to use the Webcrypto API in Typescript and compile it to Javascript code that runs in the browser.
In the Browser, accessing the Webcrypto API is simple. Just `window.crypto` or `crypto` for short.
In node.js, you have to import it from the built-in "crypto" library first:

```js
import { webcrypto as crypto } from "crypto"
```

Since I want to run it in the browser, I don't have to and also can not import it.

And here is the problem: For Typescript, I have to import the node library to get the necessary types. If I don't, this is the error:

```
src/main.ts:15:43 - error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'crypto'.
```

So, for Typescript to compile, I have to import "crypto", but for the browser to run it I must not.

Possible work-arounds I can think of are:

- tell Typescript that "crypto" (window.crypto) exists and is equivalent to crypto.webcrypto from the node library
- tell Typescript to not include the line with the import in the output Javascript file
- tell the browser to ignore that import

None of those I could find in the internet.

What I also tried is to use a dynamic import so I can conditionally import it, something like:

```js
let _crypto: any = window?.crypto
if (!_crypto) {
    _crypto = await import("crypto")
}
const crypto: any = _crypto
```

In theory, this should make the browser just ignore that "crypto" import since window.crypto exists.
But Typescript doesn't import the necessary types for dynamic imports for some reason.

In case this is needed, this is part of my code:

```js
export function sign(privkey: crypto.CryptoKey, data: any) {
    data = YSON.stringify(data)
    data = new TextEncoder().encode(data).buffer
    return crypto.subtle.sign({name: "ECDSA", hash: {name: "SHA-256"}}, privkey, data)
}
```

This function takes some data, stringifies it, and signs it using a private key.
The Y in YSON is intended.

The error is in the first line of that code snippet, I'm using the crypto.CryptoKey type.